# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in console

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, datatables

How to click to add action open the modal with ajax in laravel 5.5?

Console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
>       at addForm ((index):104)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):57)

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/dataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Oxbir</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Fixed Top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Contact List
                        <a onclick="addForm()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: -8px">Add Contact</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="contact-table" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/dataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/dataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/validator/validator.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contact-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('api.contact') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });

    function addForm() {
        save_method = "add";
        $('input[name=_method]').val('POST');
        $('#modal-form').modal('show');
        $('#modal-form form')[0].reset();
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Contact');
    }
    $(function(){
        $('#modal-form form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
            if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                var id = $('#id').val();
                if (save_method == 'add') url = "{{ url('contact') }}";
                else url = "{{ url('contact') . '/' }}" + id;
                $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type : "POST",
//                        data : $('#modal-form form').serialize(),
                    data: new FormData($("#modal-form form")[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        $('#modal-form').modal('hide');
                        table.ajax.reload();
                        swal({
                            title: 'Success!',
                            text: data.message,
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: '1500'
                        })
                    },
                    error : function(data){
                        swal({
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: data.message,
                            type: 'error',
                            timer: '1500'
                        })
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I see in console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
    at addForm ((index):104)

[image: Error sample]

Comment: looks like your `$('#modal-form form')[0]` has no value (undefined). Are you sure it exists at the time of the call?

Comment: Where you have created the modal form (modal-form)?

Seem like it doesn't include to here. The reason for this error is, you are trying to access none existing array index ($('#modal-form form')[0]) since modal form is not loaded to here

Comment: Yes I am sure.  This code is youtube

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi Well, it does not exist in the code you provided. I don't think anyone can help if you don't provide the correct code sample.